# Word: Activate "Banded Columns" automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am creating a Word-Template (.dotx). For tables the columns shall have alternating colors. So the function "Banded Columns" needs to be active.

[image: Picture to clarify the expected funtion.]

Is there a way to to activate this function automatically when a user adds a new table to his Word document?

I am using Word 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table style or modify an existing one with banding, and then set it as the default table style.

You did not specify which version of Word you're using so here's a screenshot from Word 2010 after right clicking one of the built-in table styles:

[image]

This would look similar in other versions of Word.

When you click `Set as Default` (maybe after modifying the style to fit your needs) you'll be asked if you want this to be the default for the current document or for all future documents based on the current Word template.

Comment: That looks good, unfortunately it does not change the default settings in the table style options. Banded columns is deactivated when creating a new table (I am using Word-2016).

Comment: After testing with Word 2010. It is also not working, because as far as i can see "Banded Columns" can not be activated inside the table style. It can only activated to be applied for each table style. Or am I missing something?